# How to revert to previous commit after clone?

Tags: git, github

There is a miss-updated repository for my current lesson.
It is accidentally empty, only `readme.md` is alive. All files are exist in a previous commit.
I've maked an own copy (forked).

So I want to clone my fork, and then restore all files from previous commit and be able to edit and commit again.
I've tried a lot of internet guides.
`Reset` does nothing.
`Revert` restore some, but cannot commit back.
The best approach was:

`git checkout -b tmpBranch 92f5c04` - restores commit with files on temporary branch.

`git checkout main` - goes to main for merge temporary to this

`git merge tmpBranch` - expected to merge all files from tmpBranch to my main, but nothing
adds, still only readme...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities.

Say

```
git reset --hard @~1
```

This will totally throw away the "bad" last commit, putting things in the state from the penultimate "good" commit. The entire "bad" commit and everything in it will be effectively totally erased as if it had never been.

Or say

```
git reset --soft @~1
```

This will keep the *state* (contents) of the "bad" last commit but it will all be editable so you can correct it, add, and commit correctly. That way you don't have to reconstruct the good part of the last commit from memory, if there is a good part.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've just tried your first option. It do restores previous commit (I already tried similar resetting by commit SHA).
But it is only a half of desired outcome. 
When I do `add .` , `commit -m "restored"`, `git push`, my forked repo rejecting upload.
Didn't check a second option, but probably it has similar behaviour.
How to upload (especially to `main`) after this reset?

Comment: You are rewriting history. You have to say `--force` when you push.

Comment: What a nice attribute :) Now is one of my favourites :) Works like a charm.
Greatly appreciate.

Can you also point some hint, why `git merge tmpBranch` returns 'nothing to add' in question's example?